# issue in filerobot-image-editor.min.js in manifeast file of my plugin says Refused to execute inline script because it violates the Content Security

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cdn, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

full error is

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22).

i also tried to modify manifeast file and added cdn link for it

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Your Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "http://cdn.scaleflex.it/plugins/filerobot-image-editor/2/filerobot-image-editor.min.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but after doing this extension is unable to reload and says

Could not load javascript for content script.
Could not load manifest.

I have tried above things and modified but its not working maybe its manifeast version issue earlier i used v2 it working fine but now im using v3 and i'm sucked in the above issue.

can anyone help me.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: ManifestV3 disallows remote code. Put the file in your extension directory and load it the same as your other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the link: "http://cdn.scaleflex.it/plugins/filerobot-image-editor/2/filerobot-image-editor.min.js".

Instead of "/2/", it should be "/v2/".

Here is the correct link to use:

"http://cdn.scaleflex.it/plugins/filerobot-image-editor/v2/latest/filerobot-image-editor.min.js"

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: What do you mean? The 1st URL works, the 2nd doesn't.

Comment: You can try this one out: https://cdn.scaleflex.it/plugins/filerobot-image-editor/latest/filerobot-image-editor.min.js